# Create csv based on a object property assigned dynamically

Tags: c#

I need to build a csv string based on a specific property from an object stored in a list but I've got to do this for multiple properties:

The below works fine when "hardcoded":

```
var list = customers.Select(p => p.Email).ToArray();
csvString = string.Join(";", list1);
```

but I obviously don't want to have to do this for every property I need. Is there a way for me to build a function and assign the property name I want to use to one of the parameters. Something similar to this:

```
var emails = ConvertCollectionToCsv(customers, "Email");
var names = ConvertCollectionToCsv(customers, "Name");
var mobile = ConvertCollectionToCsv(customers, "Mobile");
...
```

I thought I'd try the following:

```
private string ConvertCollectionToCsv(List<Customer> customers, string propertyName)
{
   var prop = typeof(EmailAddress).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault
   (p => p.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == propertyName.ToLowerInvariant());

   var list = customers.Select(p => prop.Name).ToArray();
   return string.Join(";", list);
}
```

but when called:

```
var emails = ConvertCollectionToCsv(customers, "Email");
```

it returns Email;Email;Email instead of the email address which makes sense as the prop.Name is used. I'm trying to use the GetValue instead:

```
var list = customers.Select(p => prop.GetValue(p)).ToArray();
```

but that's throwing the following error:

```
"Object does not match target type."
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I see, of course it will return Email;Email;Emal;... because you are are projecting the prop variable.

Comment: Sorry I've updated my answer as I left some info out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a List of `Customer`-objects to the method but use a property of `EmailAddress`, these types don't match.

I'd suggest a generic method here:

```
private string ConvertCollectionToCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string propertyName)
{
   var prop = typeof(T).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault
   (p => p.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == propertyName.ToLowerInvariant());

   var list = items.Select(p => prop.GetValue(p)).ToArray();
   return string.Join(";", list);
}
```

This way, you pass in any collection, e.g. a `List<string>` or an array like `MyCustomType[]`

Comment: You are correct. My EmailAddress property is the same name as the one used in a third-party tool I use. So the code I have mentioned above actually works but I just had to specify the namespace in `var prop = typeof(MyCompany.Bo.Customer.EmailAddress).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault` but thanks for providing a more generic way to do it.

Comment: I've just tried what you provided but it doesn't like the fact that my collection is based on a CollectionBase. I get the following error: `Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CustomerCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CustomerCollection>'`

Comment: `CollectionBase`isn't generic, but you could try to pass `customers.OfType<Customer>()` instead of `customers`

Comment: Bang on! Thanks Stephan.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the properties from the Customer, since that is were you get the value later on.

```
var prop = typeof(Customer).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault
(p => p.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == propertyName.ToLowerInvariant());
```

and this seems odd:

```
var list = list.Select(p => prop.GetValue(p)).ToArray();
```

list.Select - what is list?
isn't it rather:

```
var list = customers.Select(p => prop.GetValue(p)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I've actually sorted my problem. Conflict with Namespace but you are correct and thanks for highlight the typos! I've updated the question.